# How do I lose cheek fat?

Tags: weight-loss

I am a 15 year old male. I workout and run intensely everyday. I have a very fit body but I can’t lose cheek fat no matter what I do? Is there anything I can do about this. 
Best,
Rowan

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to spot reduce fat without resorting to something extreme like fat freezing. Most young people, as they go through puberty, will lose baby fat around their face anyway. This might happen suddenly or take some years, but maintaining low body fat and a healthy lifestyle is the best you can do at the moment. Although this isn't what you originally asked, one way to frame ones face differently may be through using hair styling?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be that you've just grown... for instance half a year ago more parts of your body ware, as your cheeks. If so - keep training, and things will be fine.

Even if that is not your case. Teens are growing in different way. For some - whole upper body stays almost as before, but legs are much longer. Or hands... Watch your family old photos. It can be your father, or uncle. Ask that person, or family for more advices.

From that perspective it can be other thing then loosing fat.